# Asp button on click event doesn't fire when RequiredFieldValidator is present within a Bootstrap modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-modal, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a Bootstrap modal within an Asp.net page. The modal has a RequiredFieldValidator on the page. I'm trying to open the modal with a Link Button or an ASP Button onclick event:

The event never fires. If I remove the RequiredFieldValidator, the event fires and the modal opens fine. There are no other controls on the page with the same ID. If I use a regular ASP Button control I experience the same issue. However, if I use an ASP CheckBox control with an OnCheckedChanged event, it works fine.

My Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="testModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="testModalTitle"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>Test Modal</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-body">                                               
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                            <textarea id="Textarea1" name="txtTextArea" rows="4" style="width: 350px;" runat="server"></textarea>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="Textarea1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<textarea id="txtTextArea" name="txtTextArea" rows="4" runat="server"></textarea>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required Field." ControlToValidate="txtTextArea" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I've tried deleting and adding a new Button control but that didn't work.

Button Click Event:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />

    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This never fires.
    }
```

The open modal button works fine but it's not an ASP button. I need to click an ASP button on the page that will perform other actions prior to executing a script that will click the modal button. The issue is that any ASP button click event will not fire on the page.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal" id="btnShowTestModal" style="visibility: visible">Test</button>
```

Comment: It looks like in the [documentation](https://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/required-field-validator/), your `textarea` with `id=Textarea1` should be `<asp:textarea id="Textarea1"...`. If that doesn't work, you can use an `asp:textbox` and enable multi-line input. It should give you the same effect.

Comment: Have you tried adding `CausesValidation="False"` to your modal button? It doesn't really make sense for you to round-trip just to open a modal though. You might consider just using an html button with the bootstrap data attributes targeting the modal to open it.

Comment: @Joe TextArea is just one control I've tried. I've also tried with ASP Drop Downs and an ASP TextBox but same results

Comment: @JonathonChase The button to open the modal works fine but it's not an ASP button. I need to click the ASP button that will perform other steps prior to executing a script from the ASP button click event to launch the modal.

Comment: What happens when you add `CausesValidation="False"` to btnTest? Is placing the modal within a panel that has Visible set to false until your button action has executed an option?

Comment: @JonathonChase My apologies. I thought you meant adding `CausesValidation="False"` to the modal button. I added this to the ASP button and it works. Thanks! But wouldn't I need to add this to every ASP button control on the page?

Comment: Any button that is going to cause a postback will attempt validation against your validators. One option to prevent this would be to add your validators to a `ValidationGroup` like `ValidationGroup="ModalValidators"`, then add whatever button you have to submit the modal with to the same validation group, as well as checking that `Page.IsValid` is true on your submission server event.